# Suddenly "Could not build Module " is coming and it happens only for iOS devices, in Simulator it is working fine

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, xcode10.2

As I am working on the iOS app since past few years, I was able to run it on devices and simulator both which is totally easy. But from few days I am facing a time wasting problem.

Whenever I am trying to build my project in iOS device it gives me "`Module Not Found Error`" also it includes other error like "`Unknown Type Name Dipatch_Queue_t`" etc. But the strange thing is it is working fine in simulator, it builds and run on simulator as it should but not in device. The error usually comes in PODS target.

**AND THIS HAPPENS WITH ALL THE APPS I AM TRYING TO BUILD IN XCODE.**

Working Environment - xcode 10.2.

Kindly suggest me what is wrong here, which I am not able to understand.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes we stuck in some weird issues which we can't debug, so this issue is one of the case where I got to know some how the framework file of whole Xcode is corrupted but you can-not debug the Xcode framework, In my case even the framework file is not opening to check whether I wrote anything mistakenly, So solution was I delete the Xcode and reinstall the same version. If you want, you can download the upgraded version of Xcode as well. So all framework files are new and it is working fine now.